# Pushing and popping strings to and from stack NASM 64bit Windows assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, nasm, messagebox

I am busy implementing the stack on a project, and I got stuck. The goal is for it to display the message in MessageboxA, but not by using any variables, but by only pushing and popping from the stack.

This is the basic idea, but when this is compiled and run the output box is blank without a title. I used the variables title and message just to clear things up, but my goal is to be able to just push and pop the literal string and not to need a variable.

```
default rel
global WinMain
extern ExitProcess
extern MessageBoxA
section .data
title:  db 'Melang64', 0
msg:    db 'hello world', 0
section .text
WinMain:
    push title
    push msg
    sub rsp, 28h
    mov rcx, 0
    pop rdx
    pop r8
    mov r9d, 0
    call MessageBoxA
    mov  ecx,eax
    call ExitProcess
```

I do not really know if it is possible to do it in such way, but as one very wise man once said, "The  more you $@#% around, the more you'll find out."

If someone could please explain to me what my errors were, as well as guide me on the right track, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at what you popped.

Comment: @RaymondChen what do you mean. I know that I popped rsi and r8, but is that a problem?

Comment: The problem is you changed `rsp` between pushing and popping so what gets popped is not what you pushed.

Comment: @harold Thank you for pointing that out, should I remove that part('sub rsp, 28h') entirely, as because it is there to make space for the messagebox, I believe

Comment: You can move it up above the pushes

Comment: @harold Thanks a lot, it works now. You cant perhaps tell me how to push those strings to the stack, if it is even possible?

Comment: Your code *does* push label addresses (of locations where you put `db ...` strings), and would pop them again if you don't change RSP between push and pop.  At least it does if their addresses fit in 32-bit sign-extended immediates, like if you link without LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  (Only `mov r64, imm64` can use a 64-bit absolute address as an immediate, not other instructions like push or even a memory-destination mov.  [How to load address of function or label into register](//stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) .  You'd use `lea rdx, [rel msg]` / `push rdx` in normal code to push a label address.)

Comment: I meant to step through the code in a debugger and look at the values of `rcx` and `r8` after the `pop rcx` and `pop r8` instructions (respectively). Are they the values you expected? Note also that the Windows ABI forbids `pop` instructions in the prologue. (Also, it requires that non-leaf functions declare unwind codes, which you do not.)